# TWO RFID READERS and ARDUINO MEGA, only one reader will read

Tags: arduino, rfid

I am trying to run 2 rfid readers (RDM 630) in an Arduino Mega 2560. I just can't figure it out why only one reader will read and the other won't. (The readers are both functional).

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial Reader1(50, 51);
SoftwareSerial Reader2(52, 53);// RX and TX

int rfid, i;
char newtag[14];

void setup()
{
  Reader1.begin(9600);    // start serial to RFID reader
  Reader2.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);  // start serial to PC 
}

void loop()
{

  if (Reader1.available() > 0) 
  { 
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Reading RFID Tag...");
    delay(100);

    for (i=0; i < 13; i++)
      {
          rfid = Reader1.read();
          newtag[i]=rfid;
      }
     Reader1.flush();
     Serial.print("RFID Tag No:");
     Serial.print(newtag);

  }

  if (Reader2.available() > 0) 
  {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Reading RFID Tag...");
    delay(100);

    for (i=0; i < 13; i++)
      {
          rfid = Reader2.read();
          newtag[i]=rfid;
      }
     Reader2.flush();
     Serial.print("RFID Tag No:");
     Serial.print(newtag);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SofwareSerial has shared resources so needs a little extra thought on implementation. When you initialise a device it is the listening device. If you initialise another the listening device changes. You need to put:

```
Reader1.listen();
```

Before your Reader1 code and switch again for your Reader2 code.
See this for example code: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TwoPortReceive

However, you say you have a Mega. Why not use the multiple serials you have onboard? Your code base will be smaller and the coding is cleaner. http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MultiSerialMega

Comment: No problem. Have fun with it!

Comment: still have a problem, everytime I swiped the Tag, the serial monitor display the tag no and another 'yyyyyyyyy'.. Is there something wrong with the code?


  **At Serial monitor:**

   ` Reading RFID Tag...
    RFID Tag No:76002C409389

    Reading RFID Tag...
    RFID Tag No:ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ

    Reading RFID Tag...
    RFID Tag No:76002C408D97

    Reading RFID Tag...
    RFID Tag No:ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ `

Answer (score 0):

After around million of trying and trying I discovered that the correct way to connect 4 RFID RC522 is to put them in the same line on test board except SS pins and the code as usual is `ReadUidMultiReader` from RFID library like this :
[image]